# Is $\int\int F(\vec{a})F(\vec{b})(\hat{a}\cdot\hat{b}) d\vec{a}\: d\vec{b}$ separable?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Assuming that we have a double integral of the form $\int\int  F(\vec{a})F(\vec{b})(\hat{a}\cdot\hat{b}) d\vec{a}\: d\vec{b}$, is it possible to fully separate the integral into a product of two?

I know that I can separate the $F(\vec{a})$ and the $F(\vec{b})$, but can I do the same with the scalar product?

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: I haven't seen this notation $d\vec{a}$ before. Let's say $\vec{a}=(x,y)$, a 2-dim vector. Is $\int F(\vec{a})d\vec{a}$ the same as $\int F(x,y)dxdy$?

Comment: $d\vec{a}$ is another way of writing $d^{3}a$ for a 3-dim vector. Yes, for a 2-dim vector is the same as what you wrote.